# getPackageInfo() throws exception when called when devices starts, but not later?

Tags: android, widget, package

I discovered some strange behaviour of the method getPackageInfo() of the PackageManager class.

I have an app widget, which relies on a particular package to be installed. So, in the onUpdate() method, I test if this package is installed:

```
public boolean isAppInstalled(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean installed = false;
    int flags = PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, flags);
        installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        installed = false;
    }
    return installed;
}
```

So, this works fine most of the time, when the onUpdate() method is called.
However, I discovered that in Android 4.03 it will falsely throw the NameNotFoundException when the devices is rebooted, that is, while booting, obviously the widgets onUpdate() method is called to "early" as it seems. When the widgets onUpdate method is called again (half an hour later), it correctly throws or doesnt throw the exception, depending on if the package is installed or not.
This only happens on Android 4.03 (didnt test Honeycomb), but 2.2 and 2.3 works fine.

Any suggestions?
Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The list of installed apps is only valid after PackageManager has finished scanning for them. The internally installed apps appear pretty quickly (possibly before you would have time to know the difference), but the externally installed apps rely on the SD card being mounted, which can take a long time on some platforms.

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any useful events or properties of PackageManger that tell you when this might be complete, so you can only rely on surrogates such as when the SD card is mounted or when the media scanner service has finished. This is only slightly better than an arbitrary delay after boot, but is the best answer I have found so far.